# How to recover unsaved PSD file on MacOSX

Tags: macos, data-recovery, forensics

Adobe Photoshop creates temporary *.psb files for emergency recovery at this path:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS6/AutoRecover
```

The files created have names like `_Untitled-10FDB62ECBABBFF5C8EAD958EBC9CFAE2E.psb` with current user:group as designated owner.

If you save the file you are working on OR you hit "don't save" when prompted, the temporary files are deleted.

Now, system creates and deletes these files. I am trying to recover the emergency file but I think the "undelete" utilities were created assuming the "user" deletes the file - like going into the trash bin and then emptying the trash...

Anyone having experience about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a traditional file system forensics tool that supports HFS+ and examine the folder contents. You will likely see deleted files. Otherwise, perform targeted file carving for *.psd files as they are virtually the same format.